# Youtube API unexpected part on Update Message {0}

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client, youtube-data-api

Been using the API for awhile now and have encountered a problem: A 400 Bad Request on "youtube.part" . Normally not a problem, I thought perhaps I have an inccorrect Part specified, the error message will tell me what is wrong and I can easily change it, however, the error is the following:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
     "domain" : "youtube.part",
     "location" : "part",
     "locationType" : "parameter",
     "message" : "{0}",
     "reason" : "unexpectedPart"
  } ],
  "message" : "{0}"
}
```

Normally in the `"message": "{0}"` it should tell you what part is wrong. Having searched on here a bit, I can't seem to find a solution, right now I am only specifying `snippet` . In building my update request I am specifying only `snippet.title` `snippet.tags[]` & `snippet.categoryId` .

The above is used in a testing environment and the request is authorized with `youtube` scope, as I use it to upload the video just before to the same youtube channel.

My own Ideas are the it is perhaps:

- Not possible to directly update a video, after loading it (however, it is possible to list)
- That I have somehow encountered a bug

For those looking to recreate what I am getting, I took the following steps in my testing:

1. Set up a youtube instance using authorised credentials
2. Upload a random small file to the channel (setting video title etc.)
3. After a successful return attempt to list the video by id
4. Using this id, retrieve video resource from youtube
5. Alter the tags section, leaving the title etc unchanged
6. Attempt to update and receive that error

Any help would be appreciated and I really hope it isn't an obvious solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when your video update request doesn't list all the parts you are including in the video object you are sending. For example, if your video object has snippet and status (because you used `video.setSnippet` and `video.setStatus`), the first paremeter in the update method has to list both parts:

```
Video ve = listVids[0];
ve.setStatus(...)
ve.setSnippet(...)
...
YouTube.Videos.Update updateVideosRequest = youtube.videos().update("snippet, status", ve);
Video videoResponse = updateVideosRequest.execute();
```

Notice the first parameter of the `youtube.videos().update`, it has both status and snippet included.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was busy elsewhere. So you were correct, the error was not caused by the the creation of the `Youtube.Videos.Update` but in a previous step. We first list the video to ensure it is present, then use that returned video as a base for the update. 

The list request had more part parts specified and thus the error is thrown.  thanks for the help