# using youtube API with Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I am not able to test my scripts.
If you can help with the code here - it is not working
As per documentation - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

```
  if (serviceYT.hasAccess()) {
  url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&mine=true&key='+ API_KEY;
  var data;
  data = '{"snippet":{"title":"testtitle","description":"testdes","categoryId":"19","tags":["asdf","sadfds"]},"status":{"privacyStatus":"public"}}';

  var options =  {
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + serviceYT.getAccessToken()
      ,'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'method' : 'POST',
    'payload' : data,
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  
  //execute and handle the response
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(result);
```

}

My questions -

1. where to put the video?
2. Resolution of the error I am getting:

{error={message='status', code=400.0, errors=[{reason=unexpectedPart, domain=youtube.part, message='status', location=part, locationType=parameter}]}}

A youtube object (a empty video basically) is successfully added to the youtube which is visible via studio. its a empty video but the title, description, status etc... other things are correcty setup.

Any ideas on how to add the media or video??
Where in the payload the video blob has to be added?

I am not able to get it in the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Youtube API unexpected part on Update Message {0}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183584/youtube-api-unexpected-part-on-update-message-0)

Comment: I did read that. That does not solves anything.

Comment: In your goal, you want to upload a movie file to your YouTube channel with the title, description, and so on. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, is it required to directly request to the endpoint using UrlFetchApp? For example, how about using YouTube API with Advanced Google services?

Comment: @RatanNahn oh my bad, I'm so sorry it does not solve anything for you, I wish it could help you

Comment: @Tanaike I would like to use google advanced services. But i get unauthorised error. But works fine with UrlFetchApp. Am I missing something to start using Google Advanced services??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload a movie file to your YouTube channel with the title, description, and so on.
- The movie file is put in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this by directly requesting to the endpoint using `UrlFetchApp`.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please enable YouTube Data API v3 and add the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`. And please set the file ID of the movie file in your Google Drive to `const fileId = "###";`.

**`serviceYT.getAccessToken()` is from your script.**

```js
function myFunction() {
  const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of movie file on the Google Drive.
  const metadata = {
    "snippet": { "title": "testtitle", "description": "testdes", "categoryId": "19", "tags": ["asdf", "sadfds"] },
    "status": { "privacyStatus": "public" }
  };

  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus';
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  let data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  data += "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
  data += JSON.stringify(metadata) + "\r\n";
  data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  data += "Content-Type: " + file.getMimeType() + "\r\n\r\n";
  const payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes().concat(file.getBlob().getBytes()).concat(Utilities.newBlob("\r\n--" + boundary + "--").getBytes());
  const options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary,
    payload: payload,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + serviceYT.getAccessToken() },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
  console.log(res);
}
```

- In your script, you are using the endpoint of `url = 'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&mine=true&key='+ API_KEY;`. Your `data` has the properties of `snippet` and  `status`. In this case, it is required to use the endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus`.
- In order to upload the movie file, it is required to request with `multipart/form-data`.
- When this script is run, the movie file on Google Drive is uploaded to YouTube.

#### Note:

- In the current stage, even when `"privacyStatus": "public"` is used, the uploaded video is not public. About this, you can see it at the official document as follows. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

  > All videos uploaded via the videos.insert endpoint from unverified API projects created after 28 July 2020 will be restricted to private viewing mode. To lift this restriction, each API project must undergo an audit to verify compliance with the Terms of Service. Please see the API Revision History for more details.
- When you use the YouTube API at Advanced Google services, you can use the following simple script. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

  ```
    function myFunction2() {
      const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of movie file on the Google Drive.
      const res = YouTube.Videos.insert({
        "snippet": { "title": "testtitle", "description": "testdes", "categoryId": "19", "tags": ["asdf", "sadfds"] },
        "status": { "privacyStatus": "public" }
      }, ["snippet", "status"], DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob());
      console.log(res);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)
- [Multipart-POST Request Using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d595d30a592979bbf0c692d1193d260c)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: I was trying this way of multipart but could not make it work. Thanks it is working now.

Also I would like to use the simple script mentioned at the bottom of @Tanaike answer.

But I get unauthrised error. Actually I am trying to connect my brand account. I thought there may be a limitation with Advanced Google services with brand account. Do let me know what should be done to start using Advanced Google services for YouTube.

Also, as I had permission, the public access for the video will work for this project. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ratan Nahn Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the relationship between YouTube API of Advanced Google services and "brand account", although I'm not sure the detail of `I get unauthrised error`, for example, in that case when you use the Google Apps Script linking with Cloud Platform Project, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution, I would like to propose to use my first script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: not poor, u r a proo.. @Tanaike ...do let me know if we can connect someway

Comment: @Ratan Nahn Thank you for replying. I think that the values for requesting between UrlFetchApp and Advanced Google services are the same. But, I cannot see the internal request of Advanced Google services. I apologize for this. And, when I tested both scripts, no error occurs. So, for example, when you use the Google Apps Script linking with Cloud Platform Project, what result will you obtain? And also, when you include the channel ID in the request body, what result will you obtain?

Comment: hmm... I made a project in Google cloud. Setup credentials and Oauth screen. Redirect URI has Google spreadsheet details. That is how I link GCP and GAS. Oauth consent screen comes when script is executed. I grant my account permission and then connect the brand account - which is completed successfully. I am able to post videos via longer method u explained but not via the short method. It gives unauthorised error as follows: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.insert failed with error: Unauthorized...its off my head

Comment: Other functions with same method are working YouTube.***... upload fails though

Comment: @Ratan Nahn Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I am able to post videos via longer method u explained but not via the short method.`, when I tested my scripts, both scripts works. So I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. But, when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. So, in the current stage, I would like to propose to use the method using UrlFetchApp. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @Ratan Nahn Thank you for replying. I cannot still replicate your new issue. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this again. About `If you could look on my setup, it may help. Can we connect on skype? Pls mail me`, I cannot do this. I deeply apologize for this. So, I would like to propose to post about the method for using your account with Advanced Google services. By this, a lot of users including me can think of your question. When you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? By the way, I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.