# How to upload a video from google drive to YouTube using google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, youtube-data-api

I found a code to upload a Video to YouTube with Google apps script. But with this i can only upload a file from a URL, not from google drive. Now, how can i upload a file from Google Drive using Google Apps Script?

That's the Code i found to upload a Video from a URL to YouTube:

```
function upload(url, title, description, topics) {
    try {
        var video = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        YouTube.Videos.insert({
            snippet: {
                title: title,
                description: description,
                tags: topics
            },
            status: {
                privacyStatus: "public",
            },
        }, "snippet,status", video);
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("done")
    } catch (err) {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput(err.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69762966/7108653

Answer (score 0):

You cant upload videos to YouTube directly from Google drive.  That is not how things work.

Files are uploaded from the machine running the code via a file stream.

## Videos private from comments.

Check the top of the documentation for [video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

[image]

Videos uploaded via the YouTube API in a project that has not yet been verified are set to private automatically you need to go though the verification process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked because if i upload a video by URL, it get's removed by YouTube automatically. (Maybe because of Copyright?) but i also tried to upload a selfmade video with an URL, but it got removed too…

Comment: Videos uploaded via the YouTube API in a project that has not yet been verified are set to private automatically you need to go though the verification process.